# UNIX file merge

Tags: file, unix, merge, timestamp

There are 3 time stamped file groups.

```
A<YYYYMMDDHHMI>.txt 
B<YYYYMMDDHHMI>.txt 
C<YYYYMMDDHHMI>.txt
```

Need to find latest time stamped file in each file group. Then merge the content of each latest file to another file **MERGE.txt**.

I have tried the below command to find the latest in each group. But I failed redirect the content to the new file.

```
ls A*.txt | sort -r | head -1
```

Anyone please suggest the code to redirect the latest file's contents to another file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

```
cat < `ls A*.txt | sort -r | head -1` >MERGE.txt
cat < `ls B*.txt | sort -r | head -1` >>MERGE.txt
cat < `ls C*.txt | sort -r | head -1` >>MERGE.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are naturally date-sorted by filename, let the shell take care of the sorting for you.

```
afiles=(A*.txt)
bfiles=(B*.txt)
cfiles=(C*.txt)
cat "${afiles[-1]}" "${bfiles[-1]}" $cfiles[-1]} > MERGE.txt
```